# Error- When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a funding table below is its admin funding show page. I want to add a feature so that the admin can add the cheque cut date directly from this page with a submit button at the end.

```
<%= form_tag add_cheque_date_path, :method => 'patch' do %>
 <tbody>
  <% @fundings.each do |funding| %>
   <tr> 
    <td><%= funding.child.parent.parent_1_firstname %></td>
    <td><%= funding.child.parent.email %></td>
    <td><%= funding.activity_start_date %></td>
    <td><%= funding.date_submitted %></td>
    <td><%= funding.status %></td>
    <td><%= date_field_tag "funding.cheque_cut_date", funding.cheque_cut_date %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "View", parent_child_funding_path(funding.child.parent, funding.child, funding) %></td>   
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>   
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
  <% end %>
```

parents_controller.rb

```
def add_cheque_date
        @fundings= Funding.all
        fundings = params[:fundings]
        @fundings.each do |funding|
        funding.update_attributes(:cheque_cut_date)
        end
    end

def funding_params
        params.require(:funding).permit(:cheque_cut_date)
    end
```

routes.rb

```
patch 'admin/application-status', to: 'parents#add_cheque_date', as: 'add_cheque_date'
```

When I click on submit below is the error i am getting. Kindly help me fix it.

```
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

Answer (score 1):

> [`update_attributes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) updates all the attributes from the passed-in
>   Hash and saves the record. If the object is invalid, the saving will
>   fail and false will be returned.

But at `funding.update_attributes(:cheque_cut_date)` you put only key `:cheque_cut_date` without any value. Try next:

```
funding.update_attributes(funding_params)
```

Also, there is more than one problem. `date_field_tag "funding.cheque_cut_date"` create field with the name `funding.cheque_cut_date`, but `params.require(:funding).permit(:cheque_cut_date)` not permit key `funding.cheque_cut_date`. Change your fields name too:

```
<td><%= date_field_tag "funding[cheque_cut_date]", funding.cheque_cut_date %></td>

#or the same fields helpers type as other from this form
<td><%= f.date_field :cheque_cut_date %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

form.html.erb

```
<td><%= date_field_tag "cheque_cut_date[#{funding.id}]", funding.cheque_cut_date, min: Date.today %></td>
```

controller.rb

```
def add_cheque_date
        fundings = params[:cheque_cut_date]
        fundings.select do |k, v|
            if v.present?
                funding = Funding.find(k)
                funding.update_attributes({cheque_cut_date: v})
            end
        end
    end
```